# No reply from rest service after creating two nodes

Tags: services

I had to fill a website with 12000 nodes , so I wrote a c# application which sends nodes (encoded in JSON format) from my local computer to website.

using services module proper resources are implemented.

now the problem is :

> after posting 2-3 nodes , REST service stops responding to my
>   application

I thought that might be caused by some limitation in REST service provided by Services Module.

Any idea how to deal with this problem? or any suggestion how to import these models to my website as a node?

Comment: Any errors in the logs of the site? Is the service returning anything? Is the site shutting down? This could be anything, more information we would need to solve your problem I think :)

Comment: @burnsjeremy No error in dblog messages. in c# application a time out exception is thrown.

Comment: I would check your server logs to see if there are any errors there, if there is a fatal error (like out of memory) then it won't ever get written to the Drupal logs b/c Drupal won't finish all of its hooks. Also there should be messages being created if you are creating nodes, if not make sure you are logging everything. Also services has a debug mode that can be turned on, turn that on to see what kind of output you can get from the services module.